# How to set vm.max_map_count in MacOS

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am running elasticsearch with docker and when i try to start elastic search it says

```
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2023-11-06T15:42:29,645][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Rc1OamK] stopping ...
[2023-11-06T15:42:29,683][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Rc1OamK] stopped
[2023-11-06T15:42:29,684][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Rc1OamK] closing ...
[2023-11-06T15:42:29,717][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Rc1OamK] closed
```

I did bit of research and the solution is to set   `vm.max_map_count` in host machine with the command `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`

But I am getting the error message as `sysctl: unknown oid 'vm.max_map_count'` similar to mentioned. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998092/docker-compose-error-bootstrap-checks-failed-max-virtual-memory-areas-vm-ma)

Any thoughts/suggestions on this?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41251595/4604579 ?

Comment: @Val I am getting error as sysctl: unknown oid 'vm.max_map_count' when I run the command sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Comment: @val kernal version is 20.0.0

Comment: You need to run that command inside the Docker container not on your Mac host